# subtract date time in sql between row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of table which contains column of program, date, group. I want to find subtraction of date that under same group.
for example, my table is:

---

```
SELECT maxList.program, (maxlist.DATE - minlist.DATE) RUNDATE, maxList 
GROUP FROM ( SELECT a.* FROM schedule a inner join ( SELECT program,Max(DATE) 
FROM schedule GROUP BY program ) b 
ON a.program = b.program )maxList 
inner join ( SELECT a.* FROM schedule a 
inner join ( SELECT program,Min(DATE) FROM schedule 
GROUP BY GROUP ) b 
ON a.program = b.program ) minList 
ON maxList.program = minList. program 


**program  | date                | group**
    a     | 04.12.2013 19:16:08 |   1
    b     | 27.12.2013 00:47:41 |   1
    c     | 30.12.2013 00:47:41 |   1
    d     | 26.12.2013 14:02:42 |   2  
    e     | 31.12.2013 12:03:42 |   2
```

---

What I want is to subtract the latest date under same group to the initial date.
for example 30.12.2013....- 04.12.2013, is there any coding that can be use to apply the subtraction in sql?

Comment: SELECT maxList.program,
       (maxlist.DATE - minlist.DATE) RUNDATE,
       maxList GROUP 

FROM
  (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM schedule a inner join
    (
      SELECT program,Max(DATE)
      FROM schedule
      GROUP BY program
    ) b ON a.program = b.program
  )maxList inner join
  (
    SELECT a.*
    FROM schedule a inner join
    (
      SELECT program,Min(DATE)
      FROM schedule
      GROUP BY GROUP 
    ) b ON a.program = b.program
  )
minList ON maxList.program = minList. program

Comment: i try with this coding,but the date subtraction did not show out subtraction by group, is that my coding contains any error?

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just aggregate the `MAX` and the `MIN`:

```
SELECT   group, 
         MIN(date) || '..' || MAX(date) AS date_range, 
         MAX(date) - MIN(date) AS days_between
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY group
```

Comment: but it show out error of: ORA-00909: invalid number of argument

Comment: @user3128278 Oh, this is Oracle. I fixed my concatination, should work now.

Comment: hi,the coding is work but it only show out the min and max date together. What I need is the date can be subtract directly, is that possible?

Comment: @user3128278 I do not understand the sentence "What I need is the date can be subtract directly". Can you clarify?

Comment: like currently the result display out 20-APR-11..23-APR-11, but I want the result can show out 3, which means the subtraction between latest date and initial date.

Comment: @user3128278 just subtract `MIN` from `MAX` - I edited my answer accordingly. If you want exact dates, you may have to add a `TRUNC` there.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   group**, MAX(date) - MIN(date) as date_diff
FROM     your_table
GROUP BY group**
```